# Webpack Dev Server PFX Configuration

Tags: node.js, webpack, pfx

I would like to serve my JS application to my Android phone, that has VR capability. Currently I have a Node server setup that is able to do this.

```
var https = require('https');
var fs = require('fs');

var options = {
    pfx: fs.readFileSync('/home/jfrye/cert.pfx'),
    passphrase: 'password'
};

var server = https.createServer(options, function (req, res) {
    console.log("request received");
    console.log(req.url);

    if(req.url == "/")
    {
        console.log("empty url, serving index");
        fs.readFile('./src/index.html', function (error, data) {
            res.end(data);
        })
    }
    else
    {
        fs.readFile('./src/' + req.url, function (error, data) {
            res.end(data);
         })
    }
}).listen(12345, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log('server running');
});
```

I am now trying to observe modern JS practices by packaging my application and serving a bundle inside the main HTML file. I want a setup where I do not need to rebuild the bundle after I make changes and re-request the app from my Android phone. My understanding is that webpack-dev-server will deliver this capability. Please correct me if I am mistaken.

Consequently, I am trying to "webpack-dev-server"-ify the Nodejs server I have above. These are my current configurations in webpack.config.js

```
devServer: {
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname),
    pfx: '/home/jfrye/cert.pfx',
    pfxPassphrase: 'password',
    port: '12345'
  }
```

I have moved index.html from ./src/ to the root directory of the project.

When I make requests to localhost:12345 or my IP address: 12345 from the Android phone, I am getting Connection Refused, which is the same behavior I was seeing before I got the right configuration on my Node server. Can anyone offer insight or provide examples of proper configuration for an HTTPs webpack-dev-server using PFX certificates?